# Apache Solr : Data import handler exception - how to skip zero byte files

Tags: solr, solrnet

While going through Solr logs, I found data import error for certain
documents. Here it is:

```
Exception while processing: file document :
null:org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: Unable
to read content Processing Document # 7866
        at
org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException.wrapAndThrow(DataImportHandlerException.java:69)
        at
org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.TikaEntityProcessor.nextRow(TikaEntityProcessor.java:171)
        at
org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.EntityProcessorWrapper.nextRow(EntityProcessorWrapper.java:267)
        at
org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:476)
        at
org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:517)
        at
org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:415)
        at
org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.doFullDump(DocBuilder.java:330)
        at
org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.execute(DocBuilder.java:233)
        at
org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.doFullImport(DataImporter.java:424)
        at
org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.runCmd(DataImporter.java:483)
        at
org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.lambda$runAsync$0(DataImporter.java:466)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.tika.exception.ZeroByteFileException: InputStream must
have > 0 bytes
        at org.apache.tika.parser.AutoDetectParser.parse(AutoDetectParser.java:122)
        at
org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.TikaEntityProcessor.nextRow(TikaEntityProcessor.java:165)
```

How do I ignore ZeroByteFileException? Can I define any setting in `dataimport.config`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is an attribute which can be configured in your case.

You can add the `ignoreTikaException=true`

```
ignoreTikaException
```

If true, exceptions found during processing will be skipped. Any metadata available, however, will be indexed.

```
Example: ignoreTikaException=true
```

For more details please refer the solr documentation.
[Solr Documentation](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_7/uploading-data-with-solr-cell-using-apache-tika.html)

```
onError
```

By default, the TikaEntityProcessor will stop processing documents if it finds one that generates an error.
If you define `onError` to `"skip"`, the TikaEntityProcessor will instead skip documents that fail processing and log a message that the document was skipped.

Comment: There was one more attribute onError="continue"...but I am not sure if that exist...I had used it earlier...

Comment: Thanks Abhijit for the update.
Iam already having "OnError" setting and still Solr failing to process the documents with above error.
<entity name="files" dataSource="null" rootEntity="false"
            processor="FileListEntityProcessor"
            baseDir="C:\Test" fileName=".*\.(pdf)"
            onError="skip"  
            recursive="true">

Regards,
Ravi kumar

Comment: then can you try with the ignoreException then

Comment: When I add  ignoreException  attribute part of configuration Solr not at all processing any documents.If possible can you please provide complete syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I identified and removed corrupted files (or) zero kb files. After that issue got resolved and Solr started processing remaining files.

Regards,
Ravi kumar